# Hide birthdays from MS Activesync calendar

Tags: calendar

I've a Samsung Galaxy A5 (2016) with Android 6.0.1

I've added recently my Microsoft Live account to it as MS ActiveSync to be able to synchronize calendar (Samsung S-Planner).

The calendar is synchronized correctly, however I can't hide birthdays and national holidays.
I want to see only my appointments, and not all those community ones.

For other accounts on my phone I can control synchronization for events / birthdays / Contacts ..., however for live account there are only "Calendar" and "Task" options.
Everything is categorized under "Calendar" if it's on I see everything, otherwise nothing.

(in web access, or MS Outlook on pc I can hide birthdays and holidays correctly).

I've searched the web for a solution, however the advice for similar situations was always to go to settings and hide holidays, which option I don't have.

[image]

Comment: Is your device set in *easy mode*?  Calendar options are curtailed in this mode

Comment: @beeshyams: No, easy mode is not enabled. Also I see details for other accounts in the calendar.

Comment: Indeed, missing seeing that bit  In case you don't get an answer, alternative calendar like [Sol](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.daum.android.solcalendar) may help. I used it long while ago and could do practically anything expected of a calendar

Comment: Have you got facebook sync as well? These notifications may be coming from other third parties sync, check if facebook is incuded

Comment: No, it's coming from "live" account. If I switch off my live calendar then also birthdays disappear (Everything is categorized under "Calendar" if it's on I see everything, otherwise nothing)

Comment: My suggestion is to do it in web outlook, sign in and disable the birthday calenders ans try syncing again